# How to control my tableview cell label?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

i am new in iPhone development. I am developing an app which contains tableview with label inside the cell. I have placed different label for each row like this `if(indexpath.row == 0)` like this for each cell row i have done it. But when i am scrolling the tableview my label are getting mixed. Please help me!

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

if (indexPath.row == 2)
{
    pendingListNumberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    pendingListNumberLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
    pendingListNumberLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft ;
    pendingListNumberLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    pendingListNumberLabel.frame = CGRectMake(240, 6, 110, 30);
    [pendingListNumberLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell addSubview:pendingListNumberLabel];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [affiliationsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
return cell;
```

Comment: little more explanation and some code wud help us better in helping u. :)

Comment: Without seeing the code, I would assume you are using a re-use identifier improperly.

Comment: are you using a custom cell or default cell. I mean to say that are you creating a separate nib for the cell view or using the same cell as provided by the tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the UILabel as a subview, that is the mistake here.
Normally you would use a custom UITableViewCell for this kind of stuff, but a quick fix is this:

```
if (indexPath.row == 2)
{
    pendingListNumberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    pendingListNumberLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
    pendingListNumberLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft ;
    pendingListNumberLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    pendingListNumberLabel.frame = CGRectMake(240, 6, 110, 30);
    [pendingListNumberLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    pendingListNumberLabel.tag = 1337
    [cell addSubview:pendingListNumberLabel];
} else {
    for (UIView * subView in [cell subviews]) {
        if ([subView tag] == 1337) {
            [subView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using reusable cells and not in a right way ..

just replace your code -

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

with this -

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
```

the above code can solve your issue, but this is not good if there are a large number of cells. In that case you should use reusable cells.

Comment: yes it was working, with this code. But iam getting the label text from the server. i have written the code in viwedidload for the web services. now my label text is not updating.

Answer (score 0):

In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, first get the selected row like this

```
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
```

then use "row" to grab your data from an `NSArray` that corresponds to the tableView rows and assign it to your cell's textLabel's text property like this

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.allItems objectAtIndex:row];
cell.textLabel.text = string;
return cell;
```

And of course you would have already created a `UITableViewCell` with a Reuse identifier like this :

```
static NSString *TableIdentifier = @"TableIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
            reuseIdentifier:TableIdentifier];
}
```

The key is using an array that corresponds exactly to your table rows.  (ie - item 0 in the Array corresponds to row 0 in the tableView) then you can't go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
else
        {
            UILabel *titleLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
            [titleLbl removeFromSuperview];
        }

if (indexPath.row == 2)
{
    pendingListNumberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    pendingListNumberLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
    pendingListNumberLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft ;
    pendingListNumberLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    pendingListNumberLabel.tag = 1;// Write here.....................................
    pendingListNumberLabel.frame = CGRectMake(240, 6, 110, 30);
    [pendingListNumberLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell addSubview:pendingListNumberLabel];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [affiliationsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
return cell;
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem of label mixing just by omitting the `if (cell == nil)` checking. Use the bellow code:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
//if (cell == nil) // Need not this checking 
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Use the cell allocation directly as above :)

Answer (score -1):

For solve this issue you can put `cell=nil;` before checking `cell== nil` condition or create cell every time. It will work but **it is not good Habit**.

This also work for Text

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

cell = nil;

if (cell == nil)

{

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

}

if (indexPath.row == 2)
{

```
pendingListNumberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

pendingListNumberLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];

pendingListNumberLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft ;

pendingListNumberLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

pendingListNumberLabel.frame = CGRectMake(240, 6, 110, 30);

[pendingListNumberLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cell addSubview:pendingListNumberLabel];
```

}

cell.textLabel.text = [affiliationsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

return cell;